# Reading XML data using LINQ, multiple elements with the same name

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, linq, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010, Silverlight 4, and C#.  I have the following data stored in an XML file:

```
<root>
      <element>TextHere</element>
      <element>TextHere</element>
      <element>TextHere</element>
</root>
```

This is my current code.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLDocument.xml");
var ElementsList = from Elements in xmlDoc.Descendants("root")
                   select new
                   {
                       ElementContent = Elements.Element("Element").Value,
                   };
```

This code only puts the very first element in the list, leaving all of the others out.  How can I rewrite this code so that it will capture ALL of the elements that are named "element" in the XML file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do it:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLDocument.xml");
var ElementsList = from Elements in xmlDoc.Descendants("element")
                   select new
                   {
                       ElementContent = Elements.Value
                   };
```

Or a little more succinct in dot notation:

```
var ElementsList = xmlDoc.Descendants("element")
                         .Select(x => new { ElementContent = x.Value });
```

Note however that you only have an enumeration of elements after this, if you want a list (as your variable name suggests) you can add a `.ToList()` after the Select:

```
var ElementsList = xmlDoc.Descendants("element")
                         .Select(x => new { ElementContent = x.Value })
                         .ToList();
```

This will list will contain 3 elements (based on your example XML.
) of an anonymous type that has a `ElementContent` property. If you do not need that property (and I would think you don't) this is a simplified version that just returns a list of string:

```
var ElementsList = xmlDoc.Descendants("element")
                         .Select(x => x.Value)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Well, that succeeded in pulling in all of the elements, however it placed them all in one string with no apparent way of separating them.  I need the contents of each element to be a separate item in the list.  Is this possible?

Comment: @BCXTreme that is not the case, the content of each element will be a separate entry in the enumeration, you might just want the list, I will edit that in.

Answer (score 2):

This would do it-

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLDocument.xml");
 var ElementsList = from Elements in xmlDoc.Descendants("root")
 select new
 {
   Element1 = (string)Elements.Element("element"),
   Element2 = Elements.Element("element").ElementsAfterSelf("element").First().Value,
   Element3 = Elements.Element("element").ElementsAfterSelf("element").ElementAt(1).Value,
 };
```